# Ruby: How to filter in a hash structure to get all the keys which are <>"1"?

Tags: ruby

I want to find some elegant way to achieve this. Maybe like follwing:

```
hash={"1"=>"1","2"=>"2"}
r=[]
hash.each do |k,v|
    if k!="1"
       r<<k
    end
end
puts r
```

Any better way to achieve this?

Comment: Do you want the key value pairs where the key is <> '1', or do you want all the keys where key <> '1'.  If you want to the key value pairs, I would use hash.select/hash.reject on the hash, if you want the keys, use hash.keys.select/hash.keys.reject.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use "array difference":

```
hash.keys - ['1']
#=> ["2"]
```

Comment: I was surprised one minute ago, but it's not only shorter, but even faster )

Comment: I haven't really measured, but I would expect select/reject to be faster as well. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
puts r = hash.keys.select { |i| i != "1" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

```
r = hash.select { |k,v,| k != "1" }
puts r
```

Hope this helps,
Ben

Comment: Select returns a hash, not the keys of the hash.  Small distinction, but the original question asked for the keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
hash.reject{|k,v| k == "1"}
```

I like reject over select with a negative test because it's more readable.  "Reject values where X == '1' is true" versus "collect values where x != '1' is true".